# spring data projection containing a nested superclass

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-rest, projection

I have two classes (cat/dog) extending one superclass (animals) and one class owner that has a relation to either a dog or a cat

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "animals")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Animal {
}

@Data
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("cat")
public class Cat extends Animal {
}

@Data
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("dog")
public class Dog extends Animal {
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Owner {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "animal_id", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Animal<?> animal;
}
```

Each of them have a projection

```java
@Projection(name = "light", types = Animal.class)
public interface LightAnimal {
}
@Projection(name = "light", types = Cat.class)
public interface LightCat extends LightAnimal {
}
@Projection(name = "light", types = Dog.class)
public interface LightDog extends LightAnimal {
}
```

I try to reference the Animal inside another projection

```java
@Projection(name = "light", types = Owner.class)
public interface LightOwner {
    LightAnimal getAnimal();
}
```

I would have hoped that the animal object would have been properly deserialized either into a dog or a cat when calling the owner with the LightOwner projection, and thus have attributes defined in child projection but it only have the ones defined the parent projection

I tried to add JsonTypeInfo annotation on LightAnimal projection but had the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Type id handling not implemented for type org.springframework.data.projection.TargetAware (by serializer of type org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionSerializer) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionResource\["content"\]-\>com.sun.proxy.$Proxy307\["animal"\])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(JsonSerializer.java:160) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:730) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at ch.mfrey.jackson.antpathfilter.AntPathPropertyFilter.serializeAsField(AntPathPropertyFilter.java:205) \~\[jackson-antpathfilter-1.0.2.jar:na\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFieldsFiltered(BeanSerializerBase.java:825) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanSerializer.serialize(UnwrappingBeanSerializer.java:136) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionResourceContentSerializer.serialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:794) \~\[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6\]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionResourceContentSerializer.serialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:767) \~\[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6\]
at org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel$MapSuppressingUnwrappingSerializer.serialize(EntityModel.java:246) \~\[spring-hateoas-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter.java:127) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(SerializerProvider.java:1142) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer.serialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:193) \~\[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6\]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer.serialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:153) \~\[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.\_serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1518) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3\]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.RepresentationModelProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(RepresentationModelProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.java:134) \~\[spring-hateoas-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4\]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR\]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) \~\[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) \~\[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) \~\[spring-security-web-5.6.7.jar:5.6.7\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) \~\[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.11.jar:2.6.11\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) \~\[na:na\]
```

Comment: nope did not have the time to continue investigating